# Rails: A user can create other users with different set of permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This might be a duplicate of a question already asked but i haven't found the one that suits my condition yet.

I am developing a system where there's a user (not an admin) who is registering himself using devise. What i want is to allow this user to create different users and provide them different set of permissions (so can't be predefined permissions and hence, cant use `cancan` as far as i am aware). To clarify more, this is the table structure i have come up with yet. Please guide me if i am going on the wrong path here.

USER:

```
id,
name,
other-details
```

PERMISSION

```
id,
name, (name of the section such as gallery, report or users)
create,
edit,
view,
user_id (the user whose permissions are defined here)
```

Here, `create`, `edit` and `view` are the permissions that the user would have. If the `edit` is true, he'll be able to edit that particular `section`. I'm sorry if this is not clear. I found Johan's answer (last one) [Database schema for ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875646/database-schema-for-acl/) match my scenario however i am not sure if its the right way. Also, i am not sure how to implement the `SET` mentioned there.

Thanx in advance. Also please feel free to ask for more details if required. I'm clueless about how right this method will be.

P.S: Newbie in Rails Here.

Comment: Hey downvoter, could you please tell me whats so wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use gem devise , cancancan & rolify for it.
Check here for references https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial.

You should add your all roles with permissions in the ability.rb file

Comment: this is what i don't want. You see as far as i understood, i would need predefined roles but i don't have that in my system. Except the user, there is no subuser who will be definitely to have the permission to edit or create a new one. I apologise if i ma not clear here.

Comment: No problem in creating roles using rolify but if u want the solution of above then you need to add a field "role" in user model in devise for sign up .https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: i have no problem adding fields to the User table in devise. Its fun stuff and i have got a grip on it. or i think i have. I'll look for in the answer you suggested deeply. Meanwhile i'll wait for other suggestions as well. Thanx

Comment: Also, i dont want roles. The role in the USER table is just to identify the parent or child user. Please see my updated post.